# Transform 3D coordinates to index of a space-filling curve (Peano, Hilbert...)

Tags: 3d, hilbert-curve, space-filling-curve

While transformation of 3D coordinates to a z-order curve was relatively straightforward ([Efficient z-order transformation in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436410/efficient-z-order-transformation-in-fortran)) I am having difficulties to wrap my head around around the math for using different space-filling curves, for example Peano or Hilbert.
Any hints on how an actual code to do the transformation might look like would be appreciated. The goal is to have a subroutine that takes xyz coordinates as an input with whatever normalization is necessary and returns the index of the space-filling curve.

subroutine(x, y, z, space_filling_index)

And related to this: I read that there are many ways to define Hilbert curves in 3D space, which would be best in terms of locality? If there is a definitive answer to this...

The application would be a reordering of cells in a Cartesian computational grid with the goal of increasing cache hits when a cell accesses its neighbors cells.

Comment: Your question can be here and you did get an answer, so everything is fine, but still consider, whether you want your next question here or at a more numerical and mathematical computing site http://scicomp.stackexchange.com Stack Overflow is generally more for coding problems and that one for mathematical methods problems. This might be the reason why there is already a vote to close your question present here. Note that although you tag the question [tag:fortran] it is not about Fortran at all.

Comment: Point taken, I removed the fortran tag. I initially added it because the implementation should be in fortran, but I see that the question is more general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Hilbert curve works by dividing recursively a cube (for 3D) using the same basic shape at every step, by rotating the curve so that the exit point of a sub-cube matches the entry point of the next cube.

A fantastic resource is the technical report [Compact Hilbert Indices](https://www.cs.dal.ca/research/techreports/cs-2006-07) by C. Hamilton. The report also introduces the compact Hilbert index for non-cubic systems.

As I wrapped my head around it I wrote a blog post in 2015: [Understanding the Hilbert curve](http://pdebuyl.be/blog/2015/hilbert-curve.html) with sample Python code for the Hilbert index and an illustration of the rotation of Hilbert "sub-cubes". As part of a particle-based Molecular Dynamics simulation code I wrote, I implemented the compact Hilbert index in Fortran, see [here](https://github.com/pdebuyl-lab/RMPCDMD/blob/master/src/hilbert.f90).

Re-discussing at length the details is "beyond the scope" of a SO answer I believe but the resources above should help you very much.